# Apache2.4.18(ubuntu)でLDAPを使ってBasic認証を実施について

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ldap

Apache2.4.18でLDAPを使ってBasic認証を実施したいのですが、同僚から以下のような説明ファイルをもらいました。

```
ユーザ名： test.dev
パスワード： test
ツリー： LDAP-DEV
ホスト名： dev.auth-ldap.co.jp
ポート番号の: 636(もしくは389)
```

このファイルを従って、Apache2の設定ファイル(/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf)を変更以下のように変更しました：

```
...
<Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
AuthType Basic
AuthName "ID/Password"
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthLDAPURL ldap://dev.auth-ldap.co.jp:389
AuthLDAPBindDN "test.dev"
AuthLDAPBindPassword "test"
require valid-user
...
</Directory>
...
```

ですが、LDAPは全然動かない、もともと接続できるcgi-bin/下のものも接続できなくなってしまいました。

Answer (score 1):

BaseDN とユーザー名を格納している属性の情報が必要です。
「ツリー」の「LDAP-DEV」が BaseDN の一部だと思うので、確認してください。

AuthLDAPURL ディレクティブの書式は下記のとおりです。(参考: [マニュアル](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html#authldapurl))

```
AuthLDAPURL ldap://host:port/basedn?attribute?scope?filter
```

例えば、BaseDN が "dc=LDAP-DEV,dc=local" で、ユーザー名の属性が "uid" の場合、下記のように設定します。

```
AuthLDAPURL ldap://dev.auth-ldap.co.jp:389/dc=LDAP-DEV,dc=local?uid
```

objectClass や他の属性でフィルターをかける場合は、下記のように設定します。

```
AuthLDAPURL ldap://dev.auth-ldap.co.jp:389/dc=LDAP-DEV,dc=local?uid?sub?(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)
```